# AngularJS routing behavior not as expected, no errors whatsoever

Tags: javascript, angularjs, django

Fellow coders of SO,

I seem to have encountered a perculiar issue with my code, i'm relatively new to angularJS so this might be an error on my behalf, yet I cannot seem to figure it out.

The use case is as follows, I have a simple django rest_framework application that works 100% (tested with the swagger UI). I'm fairly certain there is no issue whatsoever in the Django app. I wish to control the front-end using angularJS.

For some odd reason I cannot figure out, the routing in angularJS refuses to do its job.

this is my app.routes.js

```
(function () {

  'use strict';



  angular
    .module('inventaris.routes')
    .config(config);

  config.$inject = ['$routeProvider'];

  function config($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/register', {
        controller: 'RegisterController',
        controllerAs: 'vm',
        templateUrl: '/static/templates/authentication/register.html'
    }).otherwise('/');
  }
})();
```

The following code block is my app.js

```
(function () {  
  'use strict';   
  angular   
     .module('inventaris', [    
        'inventaris.routes',    
        'inventaris.config',    
        'inventaris.authentication'

     ]);
    angular
        .module('inventaris.routes', ['ngRoute']);
    angular
        .module('inventaris.config', []);
    angular
       .module('inventaris')
       .run(run);

    run.$inject = ['$http'];

    function run($http) {
        $http.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = 'X-CSRFToken';
        $http.defaults.xsrfCookieName = 'csrftoken';
    }
})();
```

Following image is an screenshot from the chrome browser with debugger open, as you can see there are no errors

So I lack the 10 reputation required to post images, here is a direct link to the image - https://i.stack.imgur.com/GVZAB.jpg

I am at a loss here, I have checked the code multiple times, perhaps i forgot a ; or , somewhere but as far as I can tell I havn't missed a single one. The console is not helping me much further either.

Expected behavior: Follow the predefined routes and load the templates according to the route.

Current behavior: Does not follow any route, django's console shows the page get's loaded with a status 200 but no content is displayed.

This is why i turn to you SO, what could the reason possibly be the angular-route is refusing the do it's job?

If any more information is required i'll gladly submit the info.

*edit* order of files in javascripts.html

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js' %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'bower_components/bootstrap-material-design/dist/js/material.js' %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'bower_components/bootstrap-material-design/dist/js/ripples.js' %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'bower_components/underscore/underscore.js' %}"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'bower_components/angular/angular.js' %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js' %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js' %}"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'bower_components/ngDialog/js/ngDialog.js' %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'lib/snackbarjs/snackbar.min.js' %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/inventaris.js' %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/inventaris.config.js' %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/inventaris.routes.js' %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/authentication/authentication.module.js' %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/authentication/services/authentication.service.js' %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/authentication/controllers/register.controller.js' %}"></script>
```

Comment: What is the order of file that u included?

Comment: where is the app.js in the list?

Comment: inventaris.js = app.js

Sorry for the ambiguity

Comment: There is a inventaris.routes.js defined just below the inventaris.config.js?

Comment: did u inluded 'ng-route.js'?

Comment: See updated post, angular-route.js is included.

Answer (score 0):

```
.otherwise({
    redirectTo : '/'
})
```

try this, it may be work

Comment: I have altered my code to resemble your tip.
Unfortunately this makes no difference.